# AG Grid SSRM Advanced filtering with Sets

Tags: reactjs, sql-server, ag-grid, ag

In AG Grid, are you able to have a SSRM that enables advanced filtering for a setColumn? Specifically thinking I can open the filter builder and choose a set column and be presented with a set of options to pick from (ex: 'colour' is choose some of 'green', 'blue', or 'red')